# gvlma and poisson: Error in if (class(x)==formula) : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, if-statement, error-handling, formula, poisson

I am running several models (linear, log+1, poisson, and negative binomial). I am assessing all these models because of the funky distribution of my data, and to be consistent with previous statistical approach used in the same field by supervisor. To assess the best model for my data I was advised to use the gvlma() package for a pass/fail of diagnostics. Everything works fine until, I run the Poisson and NB models. In my data set I do have a lot of zeros (they are important and have to be kept in/cannot be replaced), but maybe I am just speculating it might play a role. Not familiar with the gvlma() package and I cannot find anything online unfortunately. Can anyone please help solve this issue? Please!

Example to reproduce the problem:

```
a <- c(54,0,1,0,6,1,3)
b <- c(822,828,908,1051,1102,1150,1249)
c<- c(0,0,0,49,36,4,160)
d<-c(18,18,18,0,1,12,0)

trial <- glm(a ~ b + c + d, family = poisson(link = "log"))
gvlma(trial)
#Error in if (class(x) == "formula") { : the condition has length > 1

trial2 <- glm.nb(a ~ b + c + d)
gvlma(trial2)
#Error in if (class(x) == "formula") { : the condition has length > 1

#error does not persist if
trial3 <- lm(a ~ b + c + d)
gvlma(trial3)
Call:
 gvlma(x = trial3) 

                       Value p-value                   Decision
Global Stat        7.4154758 0.11549    Assumptions acceptable.
Skewness           0.7286672 0.39332    Assumptions acceptable.
Kurtosis           0.0001755 0.98943    Assumptions acceptable.
Link Function      1.7500174 0.18587    Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity 4.9366157 0.02629 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
```

I tried changing the format of the model as by

```
model <- formula(a ~ b + c + d)
model1 <- glm(model, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

but the error persists.

Comment: the code and docs suggest that this is only for linear models, are you sure you can use it on logistic, nb, etc?